# Code runs when copy/pasted as macro, but not when saved as add-in

Tags: excel, vba

As the title suggests, this code fails on the line `Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` with runtime error 1004

Why would this run when added as a module but not when saved as an add-in?

Here's the code:

```vb
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderPath = GetFolder() & "\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Next Sheet
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
 Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing if it's an Addin, then `ThisWorkbook` may not work -you may need to specify *which* workbook as `ThisWorkbook` may refer to the module the addin is placed in, which likely can't technically get a sheet added to it.  Edit: Ah, yeah, "The Workbooks property may fail, as the workbook name probably changed when you created the add-in. ThisWorkbook always returns the workbook in which the code is running." - from [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook). Try using `ActiveWorkbook` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BruceWayne suggested is a problem with deciding the correct workbook. As an `AddIn`, `ThisWorkbook` will be the `AddIn` workbook, while `ActiveWorkbook` (before opening others), will be the workbook you are running your `AddIn` into.

Simply replacing `Thisworkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` in your scenario won't work, because you would just copy the sheets from the newly open workbook, to the same.

Is a good idea to declare variables to hold this informations, then you can open as many workbooks as you want, and from where you want.

See below:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbDst As Workbook: Set wbDst = ActiveWorkbook 'Can also use Worbooks("book name here")
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = GetFolder() & "\"
Dim FileName As String: FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While FileName <> ""
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FolderPath & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    For Each Sht In wbSrc.Worksheets
        Sht.Copy After:=wbDst.Sheets(1)
    Next Sht

    wbSrc.Close
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```